# Snapping one vector layer to another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector, editing, snapping

Is there anyway to snap one set of vectors to its nearest neighbor vector in another feature class?

For example, I have a road feature class and a feature class of bridges and I want to snap the bridge FC to the Road FC.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.1.

Comment: What software, version, license level? What geometries are the vectors? ArcGIS now has a tool called Snap that will do this.

Comment: ArcGIS 10.2.1, I'll look into the Snap tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your version and software, the ArcGIS [Snap](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000007000000) tool should do what you want. It does require a Standard or Advanced license.

Alternatively, [ET GeoWizards](http://www.ian-ko.com/) has a snap polyline tool that may also work.